# Linking a category to a page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, navigation, footer, link

So I have a category in the navigation section that I would like to link to the same link that is in the footer. I've tried copying the link path that I used for the footer link and putting it in the category for the one in the navigation however it isn't working. So could someone please guide me through the process?

Answer (score 1):

in backend, go for Catalog > Catalog > Url rewrite management.

there is a default option in  magento to link category to cms pages.

better you go through this link : http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/url-rewriting

Comment: I see how that works but when I click the link, the url key is not the same as the link in the footer? How can I make these the same? I followed the steps in the tutorial.

Comment: is footer is a cms page. ? in cms pages, you have option to chnage the link.....

Comment: I'm not trying to change the link in the footer. I want the link in the navigation to link to the same page as the link in the footer. I've copied the url key for the link in the footer and tried to replace it with it's appropriate category in the manage categories section however it doesn't work. How can I change the url key for the link in the navigation to the same link as the one in the footer?

Comment: can you give the same url of footer to your category ?

Comment: essentially yes that is what I'm asking, I want them to link to the same page.

Comment: did you checked this : http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar.html  and http://www.submitdigital.com/questions/add-categories-to-footer-using-php/